# How should I parse this kind of JSON?

Tags: android, json

I'm new to JSON parsing. It would be a great help if anyone would help me with parsing this kind of json array in Android.
Thank you

```
{
  "response": 200,
  "department": [
    "Information Technology"
  ],
  "subject": [
    "ads(th)"
  ],
  "professional": [
    "cg(th)",
    "cg(lab)"
  ],
  "semester": [
    "3A",
    "5A",
    "5A"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Parse with what language?

Comment: java in Android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is ur response:

```
{
  "response": 200,
  "department": [
    "Information Technology"
  ],
  "subject": [
    "ads(th)"
  ],
  "professional": [
    "cg(th)",
    "cg(lab)"
  ],
  "semester": [
    "3A",
    "5A",
    "5A"
  ]
}
```

U can do like this

```
String responseString="" //this string is ur web service response
try {
        //JSON is the JSON code above

        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(responseString);
        JSONArray department = jsonResponse.getJSONArray("department");
        String hey = department.toString();

JSONArray subject = jsonResponse.getJSONArray("subject");
        String sub = subject.toString();

JSONArray  professional= jsonResponse.getJSONArray("professional");
        String pro = professional.toString();
//like this u can parse other JsonArray

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

*After getting those values in jsonarray u want to display it in spinner than u can do like this*

```
ArrayList<String> listdata = new ArrayList<String>();  
if (professional != null) { 
   for (int i=0;i<professional.length();i++){ 
    listdata.add(professional.getString(i));
   } 
}
```

For Display into spinner

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.SpinnerSpcial);

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, listdata);//Pass list data of Profession
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**Notes:**
You can make custom adapter also by extending BaseAdapter or ArrayAdapter for Spinner.

Hope this will help u ... if u have any questions u can ask

Comment: yess..but how can i store it and display it in spinner?
It would be a great help if you can help me with that!!

Comment: yes u can display it in spinner but what u want to display professional or semester?check below code for displaying items in spinner i can't put whole code in comment so

Comment: I am using 4 spinner and each array should go in each spinner..
can that be done?

Comment: @AnujGajbhiye i have edited the answer please check again...if u have any question u can ask...

Comment: yes u can do it with 4 diff spinner also ....as i made for profession u can make for all other 3

Comment: is there a way i can contact you..i need more help.
Please!

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
try {
    JSONObject obj_result=new JSONObject(result);
    String response=obj_result.getString("response");

    JSONArray arr_department=obj_result.getJSONArray("department");
    for(int i=0;i<arr_department.length();i++)
    {
        String  department_name=arr_department.getString(i);
        Log.d("TAG","department_name:"+department_name);
    }

    JSONArray arr_subject=obj_result.getJSONArray("subject");
    for(int i=0;i<arr_subject.length();i++)
    {
        String  subject_name=arr_subject.getString(i);
        Log.d("TAG","subject_name:"+subject_name);
    }

    JSONArray arr_professional=obj_result.getJSONArray("professional");
    for(int i=0;i<arr_professional.length();i++)
    {
        String  professional_name=arr_professional.getString(i);
        Log.d("TAG","professional_name:"+professional_name);
    }

    JSONArray arr_semester=obj_result.getJSONArray("semester");
    for(int i=0;i<arr_semester.length();i++)
    {
        String  semester_name=arr_semester.getString(i);
        Log.d("TAG","semester_name:"+semester_name);
    }

} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try { //When parsing JSON, you need try catch to handle error if occure
    JSONObject fullJSON = new JSONObject("{\"response\":200,\"department\":[\"Information Technology\"],\"subject\":[\"ads(th)\"],\"professional\":[\"cg(th)\",\"cg(lab)\"],\"semester\":[\"3A\",\"5A\",\"5A\"]}");
    int response = fullJSON.getInteger("response");
    JSONArray departement = fullJSON.getJSONArray("department");
    Log.i("", departement.getString(0));
    JSONArray semester = fullJSON.getJSONArray("semester");
    for(int i=0; i<semester.length(); i++) {
        Log.i("semester", semester.getString(i));
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    //here's the error message you can get from
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use [Gson Libray](https://github.com/google/gson)

With Gson your mapping class will be like this:

```
public class YourClass {

@SerializedName("response")
private Integer response;

@SerializedName("department")
private List<String> department;

@SerializedName("subject")
private List<String> subject;

@SerializedName("professional")
private List<String> professional;

@SerializedName("semester")
private List<String> semester;
}
```

With Gson you can transform your Json in POJO (or vice versa) easily. Check the documentation.